# How to create Django queryset filter to compare Specific value of two different tables in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```html
class Job(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    type = models.CharField(choices=JOB_TYPE, max_length=10)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_date = models.DateTimeField()
    skillRequired1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    skillRequired2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    work_experience = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    filled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class EmployeeProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    type = models.CharField(choices=JOB_TYPE, max_length=10)
    work_experience = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    emailContact = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    skill1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skill2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skill3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    skill4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    about_me = models.TextField()
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='employeeProfiles', default='default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.first_name} Profile'
```

I have two tables 'Job' and other is "employeeProfile".. I want to Compare and match 'title' of both and want to show only those 'title' which is present in Job but not in 'employeeProfile'.These two tables are in two different Models.

Comment: Please, provide us some code. It's impossible to help you now.

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow ,please check out https://github.com/RKarkee/Jobs-Portal

Comment: pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example